# Remove hardcoding of id's for contentdocument object

Tags: apex

I was using the below link to redirect to contentdocument record id which works fine.

```
<apex:outputLink value="https://XXXXXXX.salesforce.com/123440000001234" target="_blank">Test</apex:outputLink>
```

I tried removing the hardcoded value as id's will be different in production.
For that i created a method -

Comment: Are you replacing your ouputlink with commandlink and still seeing the original URL ?

Comment: Suppose i am in page ..https://cs40.salesforce.com/apex/testpage?id=a1F54000000AyhHEAS...when i click the commandlink the page still remains ...https://cs40.salesforce.com/apex/testpage?id=a1F54000000AyhHEAS....

Comment: can you remove the target=_blank and check if the redirect works, I am guessing there is a popup blocker that might be stopping the redirect.

Comment: i tried but no luck...there are some fields which are required... the page throwing error to fill those fields first. Thats y i added region tag and tried.. but still its not working..

Comment: ah there you go that was the key piece, try adding immediate="true" to the commandlink, you do not need action region . when you have required fields on the page the redirect won't let you proceed until the fields are populated, By setting immediate to true, validation rules are skipped and the action associated with the button is executed immediately; thus the name!

Comment: But be mindful that you are disrespecting your own data quality checks that you have by adding immediate attribute  https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2008/12/using-the-immediate-attribute-on-commandlinks-and-commandbuttons.html

Comment: Thanks rao..I tried some more modification.. but got stuck...can u check whats wrong..its redirecting to the same page..

Comment: Remove the actionfunction block completely, your command link should be         <apex:commandLink action="{!redirectToDocument}" value="Test Page1" immediate="true"/> try this

Comment: I have multiple contentdocument.. I need to use the same method using the same query only changing the value of document{get;set} in controller. How to do that.. i have updated my method.

Comment: i got the solution...I will post the updated one..